# Space and time complexity of list of characters, where we make every possible word from them?

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am given a list of characters, and told to write out all `'combinations'` (not quite combinations) of these characters.

```
e.g. [w,x,y,z] -> w,wx,wxy,wxyz,wy,wyz,wz| x,xy,xyz,xz| y,yz
```

What is the `space and time complexity` of this?

For TC, I was thinking that as we iterate the list, for each element we have less and less combinations to choose from- but this isn't quite combination; any ideas what this pattern is?

Similar for SC, if I could identify the pattern for each element then the TC and SC would be easy to determine.

Comment: It’s only an algorithm or code implementation that you can estimate a time/space complexity for; so write some code to implement the problem and then work out the complexity of your code. Looking at the nesting of for/while loops will give you a start for time complexity; e.g. two nested for loops is at least O(n^2).

Comment: Space and Time Complexity are for algorithm/code. I don't see any algorithm here. Please write a working algorithm and only then you can know the TC and SC.

Comment: You are computing the powerset, although in your example you omit the empty string and `z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every letter, there can be 2 options: whether to keep that letter in combination or not to take that letter. If you follow a recursive approach for the same, the Time Complexity will turn out to be O(2^n).

Now, the number of combinations will also be 2^n. So, the Space complexity also becomes θ(n*(2^n)).

Comment: You've correctly counted the number of words in the output. However it takes Theta(n*2^n) space to store all the words, since of the 2^n words, the length of the words varies from 0 to n and the distribution is centered symmetrically around n/2. If instead of storing them, you're writing them to an output, then the runtime is at least n*2^n but the space complexity can easily be O(n) (for example using recursion).

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Thanks for pointing :)